# Comparing nullable ints

Tags: c#

In many places throught app I've seen stuffs like this:

```
(int)f.Status == something.Status
```

And this `Status` property is:

```
public int? Status { get; set; }
```

What I am trying to achieve is comparing nullable `int`s (`int?`) so that they are equal only if they both have a value **and the value is the same**. In particular, if they are both `null` I want them to be identified as **not** equal.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: `f.Status.HasValue && f.Status.Value == something.Status`

Comment: Does `f.Status == something.Status` work? I suspect the `int` cast isn't needed. You can compare a nullable int to an int just fine.

Comment: `int? nullint = null; int nonullint = (int) nullint;` throws `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`. This code just throws an exception if `f.Status` is null, otherwise compares the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest rewriting condition into this:

```
f.Status.HasValue && something.Status.HasValue && f.Status == something.Status
```

It would prevent you from exceptions.

If any of statuses is just and `int` and not an `int?`, then you can omit `HasValue` check.

Already given answer suggests using simple `==`, but it will return `true` in case both are `null`s, opposite to suggested. You have to decide if that's desired behaviour.

As mentioned it could be simplified to

```
f.Status.HasValue && f.Status == something.Status
```

in case of both `null`s result will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using:

```
f.Status == something.Status
```

*assuming the two properties are either `int` or `int?`*.

C# will allow you to compare `int` vs `int?` without an explicit cast.

*For future readers, this answer was written prior to the OP making clear that comparing `null` to `null` was expected to return `false`.*

Answer (score 2):

This code is risky and it can give you `NullReferenceException` if `f.Status` is null.

You can check first if it has value -> `f.Status.HasValue` before casting to integer.

You can do this to prevent exception:

```
if (f.Status.HasValue && f.Status == something.Status)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question has already been answered, but here's another way of comparing nullable values.

```
if ((f.Status ?? 0) == something.Status){
 //enter code here
}
```